# Given a sequence of positive numbers $\left\{c_n\right\}_{n \geq 0}$ satisfying $c_{n+1}=\sqrt{c_n}+\sqrt{c_{n-1}}$ for $n \geq 1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Given a sequence of positive numbers $\{c_n\}_{n \geq 0}$ satisfying $c_{n+1}=\sqrt{c_n}+\sqrt{c_{n-1}}$ for $n \geq 1$, prove that the limit $\lim _{n \to \infty} c_n$ exists and find the value of this limit.

This is a difficult problem. I tried using the squeeze theorem, but it seems that I need to consider many cases for $c_n$, and my proof cannot proceed further.

Comment: See e.g. [How to prove this limit exists: $a_{n+2}=\sqrt{a_{n+1}}+\sqrt{a_{n}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/574549/how-to-prove-this-limit-exists-a-n2-sqrta-n1-sqrta-n)